# Identifying layers by grouping using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, group-layer

I have a number of layers that I want to manipulate with ArcPy. On my ArcGIS Pro map I have them under a group layer.

To deal with them, I have been picking them by name as follows:

```
for theLayer in theMaps.listLayers():
    # print (theLayer.name)
    if theLayer.supports("ISFEATURELAYER"):
        if theLayer.isFeatureLayer and theLayer.name[:10] == "....":
```

but I'm wondering if I cannot just reference them by group?

Parsing the name creates an admin overhead to rename the sources first.

Something like

```
if theLayer.belongsToGroupLayer("MyGroupLayerName"):
```

or

```
if theLayer.parentlayer == "MyGroupLayerName":
```

The [Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) class documentation does not offer any solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/listing-layers-in-a-group/td-p/736543

```
proj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = proj.listMaps()[0]
ml = m.listLayers()
for l in ml:
   if l.isGroupLayer and l.name=='somegroupname':
      print(l)
      lyrs = l.listLayers()
      for lyr in lyrs:
         print(lyr)
```

[image]